# Convert date to character in a data frame

Tags: r

I would like to convert date columns (Date, POSIXct, POSIXt) into character columns in a data frame. For example, I have this data frame.

```
df <- data.frame(date = Sys.Date(), time = Sys.time(), val = 1)
```

I can easily use the manual way like this to convert date columns into character columns.

```
df$date <- as.character(df$date)
df$time <- as.character(df$time)
```

Is there any way that I can convert them in a whole without specifying the date columns one by one? How could I convert them using `lapply` or `sapply` function?

Comment: do u mean, if u have 3 date columns, u want to convert all 3 column at once. True?

Comment: Try `df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)`. The square parenthesis are meant to keep the shape of `df`.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I would like to convert them all in once without specifying the columns manually.

Comment: @RuiBarradas what if I have numeric columns? I just want to convert the date columns.

Comment: OK, just give a moment. Note that in your posted example that was not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make a more complete example, with a mix of data types. Then, determine which ones are of class `Date` or `POSIXt`. And finally, modify just the ones of interest.

```
df <- data.frame(date = Sys.Date(), time = Sys.time(), x = 1, A = "Test")

inx <- sapply(df, function(x) inherits(x, "Date") || inherits(x, "POSIXt"))
df[inx] <- lapply(df[inx], as.character)
str(df)
#'data.frame':   1 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ date: chr "2017-11-05"
# $ time: chr "2017-11-05 08:30:19"
# $ x   : num 1
# $ A   : Factor w/ 1 level "Test": 1
```

Note that other date/time classes such as `POSIXct` and `POSIXlt` both inherit from class `POSIXt` so you only have to test this latter.